# Number formatting in BASH with thousand separator

Tags: bash, unix, localization, number-formatting

I have a number `12343423455.23353`. I want to format the number with thousand separator. So th output would be  `12,343,423,455.23353`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
$ printf "%'.3f\n" 12345678.901
12,345,678.901
```

Comment: So `'` in `printf` puts thousands separator?

Comment: Found it,  *\` ' '    Separate the digits into groups as specified by the locale specified for the \`LC_NUMERIC' category*

Comment: There is no thousands separator in the C/POSIX locale, so `printf "%'.3f\n" 12345678.901` prints `12345678.901` if the locale variables are unset. `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%'.3f\n"` always uses comma as a thousands separator.

Comment: @user495470 Your solution will fail in most environments because it does not pass `LC_ALL` to `printf`, which is a shell builtin. As such, `printf` [does not get its own execution environment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10939280); it never actually gets to _see_ the `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` in your command line. (Just try it out with an empty environment and watch it fail.)  
The issue can be fixed by prepending `env` (which comes with both the GNU coreutils and BSD environments): `env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 printf "%'.f\n"`. This works for me on any platform, and with either GNU Bash v3 or v4.

Comment: this is much better than numfmt, plus it's a built-in.

Comment: @Synoli If someone want to see their number in their own cultural format they should have an environment with correct locale settings. You can not expect your locale to be default in empty environment.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim Regardless of which number format you prefer and no matter how the environment is configured to begin with: there’s no way you can pass `FOO=bar` to the `printf` shell builtin by running `FOO=bar printf` in a shell. That’s just not how the shell works.

Answer (score 27):

**tl;dr**

- **Use `numfmt`**, if *GNU* utilities are available, such as on Linux by default:

  - `numfmt --grouping 12343423455.23353   # -> 12,343,423,455.23353 in locale en_US`
- Otherwise, **use `printf` with the `'` field flag wrapped in a *shell function*** that **preserves the number of input decimal places** (does not hard-code the number of *output* decimal places).

  - `groupDigits 12343423455.23353   # -> 12,343,423,455.23353 in locale en_US`
  - See the bottom of this answer for the definition of `groupDigits()`, which also supports *multiple* input numbers.
- **Ad-hoc alternatives involving subshells** that **also preserve the number of input decimal places** (assumes that the input decimal mark is either `.` or `,`):

  - A modular, but somewhat inefficient variant that accepts the input number via *stdin* (and can therefore also be used with *pipeline input*):
    `(n=$(</dev/stdin); f=${n#*[.,]}; printf "%'.${#f}f\n" "$n") <<<12343423455.23353`
  - Significantly faster, but less modular alternative that uses intermediate variable `$n`:  `n=12343423455.23353; (f=${n#*[.,]} printf "%'.${#f}f\n" "$n")`
- Alternatively, consider use of my Linux/macOS **[`grp` CLI](https://github.com/mklement0/grp-cli)** (installable with `npm install -g grp-cli`):

  - `grp -n 12343423455.23353`

In all cases there are **caveats**; see below.

---

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375024/45375) contains the crucial pointer for use with `printf`: the `'` field flag (following the `%`) formats a number with the active locale's thousand separator:

- Note that `man printf` (`man 1 printf`) does not contain this information itself: the *utility* / shell builtin `printf` ultimately calls the *library function* `printf()`, and only `man 3 printf` gives the full picture with respect to supported formats.
- Environment variables `LC_NUMERIC` and, indirectly, `LANG` or `LC_ALL` control the active locale with respect to number formatting.
- Both `numfmt` and `printf` respect the active locale, both with respect to the thousands separator and the decimal mark ("decimal point").
- Using just `printf` by itself, as in Ignacio's answer, requires that you *hard-code* the number of *output* decimal places, rather than preserving however many decimal places the input has; it is this limitation that `groupDigits()` below overcomes.
- `printf "%'.<numDecPlaces>f"` does have one advantage over `numfmt --grouping`, however:

  - `numfmt` only accepts *decimal* numbers, whereas `printf`'s `%f` also accepts *hexadecimal* integers (e.g., `0x3e8`) and numbers in decimal *scientific notation* (e.g., `1e3`).

#### Caveats

- **Locales without grouping**: Some locales, notably `C` and `POSIX`, by definition do NOT apply grouping, so use of `'` has no effect in that event.
- **Real-world locale inconsistencies across platforms**:

  - `(LC_ALL='de_DE.UTF-8'; printf "%'.1f\n" 1000) # SHOULD yield: 1.000,0`
  - **Linux**: yields `1.000,0`, as expected.
  - **macOS/BSD**: Unexpectedly yields `1000,0` - NO grouping(!).
- **Input number format**: When you pass a number to `numfmt` or `printf`, it:

  - *mustn't* already contain digit grouping
  - ***must* already use the *active* locale's decimal mark**
  - For example:

    - `(LC_ALL='lt_LT.UTF-8'; printf "%'.1f\n" 1000,1) # -> '1 000,1'`
    - OK: input number is not grouped and uses Lithuanian decimal mark (comma).
- **Portability**: POSIX doesn't *require* the [`printf` *utility*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (as opposed to the C `printf()` *library function*) to support floating-point format characters such as `%f`, given that POSIX[-like] shells are integer-only; in practice, however, I'm not aware of any shells/platforms that do not.
- **Rounding errors and overflow**:

  - When using `numfmt` and `printf` as described, round-trip conversion occurs (string -> number -> string), which is subject to rounding errors; in other words: **reformatting with digit grouping can lead to a different number**.
  - Using format character `f` to employ [IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), only **up to 15 [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)** (digits irrespective of the location of the decimal mark) are *guaranteed* to be accurately preserved (though for specific numbers it may work with more digits). <sup>In practice, `numfmt` and *GNU* `printf` can accurately handle *more* than that; see below. If anyone knows how and why, let me know.</sup>
  - With too many significant digits or too-large a value present, the **behavior differs between `numfmt` and `printf`** in general, and **between `printf` implementations across platforms**; for example:

**`numft`**:

*[Fixed in coreutils 8.24, according to [@pixelbeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4421/pixelbeat)]* Starting with 20 significant digits, the value overflows quietly(!) - presumably a bug (as of GNU coreutils 8.23):

```
# 20 significant digits cause quiet overflow:
$ (fractPart=0000000000567890; num="1000.${fractPart}"; numfmt --grouping "$num")
-92.23372036854775807    # QUIET OVERFLOW
```

By contrast, a number that is too large *does* generate an error by default.

**`printf`**:

Linux `printf` handles up to 20 significant digits *accurately*, whereas the BSD/macOS implementation is limited to 17:

```
# Linux: 21 significant digits cause rounding error:
$  (fractPart=00000000005678901; num="1000.${fractPart}"; printf "%'.${#fractPart}f\n" "$num")
1,000.00000000005678902  # ROUNDING ERROR

# BSD/macOS: 18 significant digits cause rounding error:
$  (fractPart=00000000005678; num="1000.${fractPart}"; printf "%'.${#fractPart}f\n" "$num")
1,000.00000000005673  # ROUNDING ERROR
```

The Linux version never seems to overflow, whereas the BSD/macOS version reports an error with numbers that are too large.

---

#### Bash shell function `groupDigits()`:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   groupDigits num ...
# DESCRIPTION
#   Formats the specified number(s) according to the rules of the
#   current locale in terms of digit grouping (thousands separators).
#   Note that input numbers
#     - must not already be digit-grouped themselves,
#     - must use the *current* locale's decimal mark.
#   Numbers can be integers or floats.
#   Processing stops at the first number that can't be formatted, and a
#   non-zero exit code is returned.
# CAVEATS
#   - No input validation is performed.
#   - printf(1) is not guaranteed to support non-integer formats by POSIX,
#     though not doing so is rare these days.
#   - Round-trip number conversion is involved (string > double > string)
#     so rounding errors can occur.
# EXAMPLES
#   groupDigits 1000 # -> '1,000'
#   groupDigits 1000.5 # -> '1,000.5'
#   (LC_ALL=lt_LT.UTF-8; groupDigits 1000,5) # -> '1 000,5'
groupDigits() {
  local decimalMark fractPart
  decimalMark=$(printf "%.1f" 0); decimalMark=${decimalMark:1:1}
  for num; do
    fractPart=${num##*${decimalMark}}; [[ "$num" == "$fractPart" ]] && fractPart=''
    printf "%'.${#fractPart}f\n" "$num" || return
  done
}
```

Comment: The only solution that words with redirection pipe, thanks!

Comment: Why is this starting from right in your first example of your npm pkg? `grp 1000000 2000
1 000 000 
2 000`. It seems start from left?

Comment: @Timo, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but note that the command you're showing has _seven distinct arguments_ that are _individually_ subject to grouping.