# Cannot set environment variable before command

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to set a variable before calling a command in bash (on Mac):

```
BRANCH=test echo "$BRANCH"
```

But I get an empty echo.

`printenv` also has no other variable with the same name:

```
$ printenv | grep BRANCH
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct way:

```
BRANCH='test' bash -c 'echo "$BRANCH"'
test
```

To execute `echo` command you'll need `bash -c` to execute it after assignment.

Comment: What is the difference between `BRANCH='test' bash -c 'echo "$BRANCH"'` and `BRANCH='test' echo "$BRANCH"`?

Comment: You could also use: `( BRANCH='test' && echo "$BRANCH" )` I guess in first case assignment isn't processed unless `bash -c` forks a new sub-process.

Comment: I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10938530/454103) explains it well.

Comment: Two things to note: first, `$BRANCH` is expanded *before* `echo` starts, before `echo` could look in its environment. Second, `echo` ignores its environment anyway. There's no need or ability to use an environment variable here, so just use `echo test`.