# How is Bash interpreting these statements?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
$ a=one; echo $a  
one
$ a=two echo $a
one  
$ echo $a
one
```

The value of `a` will be initialized to 'two' but why is it displaying 'one'?

Comment: Works fine for me.

```bash-3.2$ a=one
bash-3.2$ echo $a
one
bash-3.2$ a=two
bash-3.2$ echo $a
two```

Comment: Ya i agree with you but, what's wrong with my script running on fedora 21?

Comment: I can verify the behavior but I cannot explain it. Interesting question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same line initialization of env variables is only available for sub shells.

It will be more evident from these examples:

```
unset a

a=two echo "<$a>"
<>

a=two bash -c 'echo "<$a>"'
<two>

echo "<$a>"
<>
```

In the 2nd snippet it prints `<two>` because we're spawning a sub-shell using `bash -c`.

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30984437/548225

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your example before posting mine.

Comment: Oh no issues, you have added a very good explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the order in which the shell processes substitutions and variables.  According to [POSIX rules for a shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01):

> When a given simple command is required to be executed (that is, when
>   any conditional construct such as an AND-OR list or a case statement
>   has not bypassed the simple command), the following expansions,
>   assignments, and redirections shall all be performed from the
>   beginning of the command text to the end:
>
> 1. The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to Shell Grammar Rules are saved for processing
>      in steps 3 and 4.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections shall be expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the first
>      field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are
>      the arguments for the command.
> 3. Redirections shall be performed as described in Redirection.
> 4. Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and
>      quote removal prior to assigning the value.

That means that the variable assignment is performed after parameter expansion has occurred, e.g. `$a` is expanded before the `a=` variable assignment for that command has been processed.  The new value of `a` will be passed into the execution environment of the command but it won't be of any use in this case with `echo`.

You can perhaps see better what's going on if you use a variable that does not already exist.

```
$ unset a
$ a=two echo \($a\)
()
$ a=one
$ a=two echo \($a\)
(one)
```

Here's an example where you can see that the variable assignment is passed to the execution environment of the command that is executed:

```
$ a=one
$ a=two python -c 'import os;print(os.environ["a"])'
two
```

---