# How to work grep and awk command?

Tags: bash

I am writing this script, but it does nothing other than blink the cursor

```
ifconfig wlan1 down && iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor; Essid=`airodump-ng wlan1  2>&1 | grep 38:EF:A5:8B:5D:85 | awk '{print $11}' ` echo $Essid
```

Comment: You mean it hangs, or does it do nothing and give you a command prompt back?

Comment: Break it into parts: try one command at a time and tell us which command it is that is giving you trouble.  P.S. You need a semicolon before the final `echo` command.

Comment: The part when Essid is being set as a variable, has the issue. airodump-ng wlan1 it's not being piped through all the way

Answer (score 1):

If it is all written on one line as shown in the question, the `echo` is run with a funny environment variable (`Essid`, set to the result of a command), but it echoes nothing because the environment variable isn't set when the argument list is evaluated.  (See [Bash: Specifying environment variables for `echo` on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938483/) for more information.)

If you are sane and write it on multiple lines, then you're in with a decent chance:

```
ifconfig wlan1 down && iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
Essid=$(airodump-ng wlan1 2>&1 | grep 38:EF:A5:8B:5D:85 | awk '{print $11}')
echo $Essid
```

Now you have a decent chance of it working as expected.  Note that if the `ifconfig` command fails to take `wlan1` down, then it won't be brought back up with the `iwconfig` command (or `ifconfig` command if that's a typo in the question).

Remember: 'one-liner' is a pejorative term unless you're writing in APL.  The shell is not APL.