# Why do bash environment variables differ in shell versus node?

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables

Run these commands in Bash:

1. `NODE_ENV=production echo $NODE_ENV` outputs ""
2. `NODE_ENV=production && echo $NODE_ENV` outputs "production"
3. `export NODE_ENV=production && echo $NODE_ENV` outputs "production"

Now there is a file index.js:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

then run these commands in Bash:

4. `NODE_ENV=production node index.js` outputs "production"
5. `NODE_ENV=production && node index.js` outputs "undefined"
6. `export NODE_ENV=production && node index.js` outputs "production"

I get confused by these commands, why are the results different?

Edit:

Thanks everyone. Now I give my explanations, maybe it's helpful for other guys.

`NODE_ENV=production echo $NODE_ENV`, Bash expends `$NODE_ENV` before running this command, at this point `$NODE_ENV` is not set so the result is blank.

`NODE_ENV=production && echo $NODE_ENV`, these are two commands, the second command command only runs if the first command succeeds. Before running the second command Bash expends `$NODE_ENV` which is set at this point.

`NODE_ENV=production node index.js`, prefixing a variable definition to a command makes this variable available to this command.

`NODE_ENV=production && node index.js`, node is an external commands, Bash forks it and runs it in a sub-process, node doesn't get `$NODE_ENV` from parent process.

`export NODE_ENV=production && node index.js`, `export` makes the variable available to sub-processes, so node gets `$NODE_ENV`.

Comment: Related: [specifying environment variables for echo on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938483/bash-specifying-environment-variables-for-echo-on-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

Few points first:

- `&&` is a logical operator that separates two commands (the second one runs only if the first one succeeds)
- For `var=value some_command`, the variable `var` is passed to the environment of `some_command`, only after shell performs all expansions on `some_command`

Now:

- `NODE_ENV=production echo $NODE_ENV`: shell runs `echo $NODE_ENV` first and `NODE_ENV` is unset while running and hence the output is blank; the variable `NODE_ENV=production` can only be passed to the expanded environment like i told earlier
- `NODE_ENV=production && echo $NODE_ENV` has two commands; as the declaration comes in the first (and succeeds) and hence `NODE_ENV` will have the value `production` in the second command. Note that, the variable `NODE_ENV` will not be passed to the expanded environment of the second command.
- `export NODE_ENV=production && echo $NODE_ENV` is like the above with the fact that you are making `NODE_ENV` available throughout the environment (all subprocesses) by `exporting`-ing. Hence the variable will be available to the second command in the expansion time and also to its environment.

Similar logics apply to the `node` commands (and all other alike cases) too.

Comment: I'm not sure your first bullet point is entirely accurate. The environment variable `NODE_ENV` is indeed set to `production` while the `echo` is running... it's just that that variable isn't used in expanding its command line, and so has no effective impact on output.

Comment: ...this is pertinent when you have environment variables like `POSIXLY_CORRECT` that (for some implementations) can change how `echo` itself behaves.

Comment: Charles, so the command exists in the environment but its usage depends on the variable itself?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that comment. Expanding parameters, as you know, happens before per-command environment variables are applied -- but those variables *are* still applied, and some values can/will change how commands behave at runtime. (If one wants to use environment variable names that one is assured won't change commands' behavior, the set of variable names with at least one lower-case character is reserved for this purpose).

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html for the standards document establishing that convention.

Comment: As an easy example that works even on non-GNU systems [subject to the following caveat about localizations available]: `LANG=ja echo hello >&-` will, if your system has the appropriate translation table installed, emit a different error message than `LANG=en echo hello >&-` (both fail because stdout is to a closed file).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I have just added my explanations to the question description, could you help to check it ?

Comment: @IvanYan, answers should be added as answers, not as question edits. If the existing answers aren't sufficient, you're welcome to add your own.

Comment: @IvanYan, ...that said, reading those explanations, they are indeed correct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, this question is marked as duplicate, I could not add an answer...