# Difference between setting a variable in a command vs setting variable before the command

Tags: bash

Why does in the second case, the value is not used by the command followed?

```
$ x=1
$ echo $x
1
$ x=2 echo $x
1
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30984437/10248678) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Does this case has the same reason: Execute a script having `echo $x` like `x=1 bash script.sh`? Coz this also gives the output as 1. Though comparing x with 2 in the script computes out as true.

Comment: Can't reproduce on bash 5.0 and bash 5.1 here. It prints `2` and `2`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it again, and its indeed 2 and 2. Not sure, what was different that time. Will re-edit the question to remove this part for future viewers.