# Environment variable isn't getting set

Tags: bash

If I run the command

```
FOO=bar echo $FOO
```

I would expect it to `bar`, but it just echoes an empty string.

It appears that `$FOO` is not getting set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/10938483/3001761?

Comment: Environment variables in  your shell commands are evaluated *before* the command executes. You need to ensure that the variable expansion happens in the child process. Try `FOO=bar sh -c 'echo $FOO'` and see if that produces different behavior.

Comment: Or with evil eval: `FOO=bar eval 'echo $FOO'`

Comment: Or `FOO=bar; echo $FOO`, with the side-effect that `FOO` remains set

Comment: This is [BashFAQ/104](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/104)

Comment: The environment variable *is* set; `echo` just ignores its environment. The expansion of `$FOO` to produce the *argument* to `echo` is an entirely separate situation.