# How to insert thousand separator with in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a text which randomly contains some numbers and I want to find them and separate thousands.

Input

```
Some random text 123456 and other text 987654 etc.
```

Output

```
Some random text 123 456 and other text 987 654 etc.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would a perl solution work?

Comment: do you have decimal numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number formatting in BASH with thousand separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374868/number-formatting-in-bash-with-thousand-separator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task has some corner cases. My first attempt for integers only would be this recursive `GNU sed` command:

```
sed -r ':a;s/([0-9])([0-9]{3}([^0-9]|$))/\1 \2/;ta'
```

Demo:

```
$ echo 'Some random text 123456 and other text 9876522224
5464, 83478234 and 2312.' | sed -r ':a;s/([0-9])([0-9]{3}([^0-9]|$))/\1 \2/;ta'
Some random text 123 456 and other text 9 876 522 224
5 464, 83 478 234 and 2 312.
```

Comment: Nicely done; the following works with both GNU and BSD (OSX) Sed: `sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{3}([^[:digit:]]|$))/\1 \2/;ta'`

Comment: A POSIX-compliant solution is possible, but cumbersome, because POSIX Sed only supports BREs (basic regular expressions) and POSIX BREs do not support alternation (`|`); essentially, you have to handle the alternation by duplicating the regex and varying the ending: `sed -e ':a' -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\([^[:digit:]]\)\)/\1 \2/;ta' -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]]\{3\}$\)/\1 \2/;ta'`